# how to prevent jquery validate form only one button?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I used KnockoutJS and Jquery Validate. It worked perfectly if i has one button. Now I want another button like this:

```
<button data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">Submit</button>
<button data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">Reset</button>
```

Problem is: when Reset button click to reset input field to empty, it also run validate like submit button. How to prevent validate when click Reset Button?

My code:
cshtml

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        Old Password
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" type="text" data-bind="value: OldPassword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        New Password
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" type="text" data-bind="value: NewPassword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="middle">
        Confirm New Password
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="confirmNewPassword" name="confirmNewPassword" type="text"
            data-bind="value: ConfirmNewPassword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <button data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">
            Submit</button>
        <button data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">
            Reset</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

KnockoutJs

```
if (!!$('form')) {
                    $('form').validate({
                        submitHandler: function () { params.viewModel.Presenter.CheckPassword(); },
                        rules: {
                            oldPassword: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 3
                            },
                            newPassword: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 3
                            },
                            confirmNewPassword: {
                                equalTo: '#newPassword'
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: for non-humans, that isn't a form

Comment: this table and button already in my form. I mean when i click the button (submit and reset), it'll validate. I want to ask how to prevent it validate when click reset button ?

Comment: it looks like a form, but it isn-t without the form tags. I am not sure if you know they exist or you just simply omitted it on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the type to your buttons and the reset will work...

```
<button type="submit" data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" data-bind="jqueryui: 'button'">Reset</button>
```

Comment: The reset button with type="reset" works only with form tag, which is not present here.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav: please see @Stiger's comments above - `this table and button already in my form`. I believe that part was omitted in the code above.